# scanf "extra input" required

Tags: c, scanf

for some simple HW code I wrote I needed to get 7 arguments via the scanf function:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d\n", &vodka, &country, &life, &glut);
scanf("%d\n", &ageof);
scanf("%d\n", &dprice);
scanf("%d\n", &mprice);
```

as you can see, I'm asking for 7 arguments in this order:

argument [space] argument [space] argument [space] argument (down line)

argument (down line)

argument (down line)

argument (down line)

BUT, when running the code, I'm suddenly required to input 8 of them, and I have no idea why....

any help anyone?

Comment: Remove `\n` from `scanf`.

Comment: If you want to force the "(down line)", then you should read lines with `fgets` and parse the lines with `sscanf`. With `scanf` the user can type all the numbers on a single line, or each number on a separate line, and you'll never know the difference.

Comment: Ok, then haccks was right. Here's what the man page says about the `\n`: *"White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input."* So the `\n` simply doesn't work the way you expected it to work.

Comment: aha. got it.
thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

As explained by [@chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905284/2410359) and [@Blue Moon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905283/2410359) a white space in the format, be it `' '`, `'\n'`, `'\n'` or any white-space does the same thing.  It directs `scanf()` to consume white-space, such as `'\n'` from an <kbd>Enter</kbd>, until non-white-space is detected. That non-white-space character is then put back into `stdin` for the next input operation.

`scanf("%d\n", ...)` does not return until some non-white space is entered after the `int`.  Hence the need for the 8th input.  That 8th input is not consumed, but available for subsequent input.

---

The best way to read the 4 lines of input is to .... drum roll ... read 4 *lines*.  *Then* process the inputs.

```
char buf[4][80];
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  if (fgets(buf[i], sizeof buf[i], stdin) == NULL) return Fail;
}
if (sscanf(buf[0], "%d%d%d%d", &vodka, &country, &life, &glut) != 4) {
  return Fail;
}
if (sscanf(buf[1], "%d", &ageof) != 1) {
  return Fail;
}
if (sscanf(buf[2], "%d", &dprice) != 1) {
  return Fail;
}
if (sscanf(buf[3], "%d", &mprice) != 1) {
  return Fail;
}
// Use vodka, country, life, glut, ageof, dprice, mprice
return Success
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have a *whitespace* in the format string, you tell `scanf()` to ignore *any* number of whitespace characters. So the *spaces* you have between the `%d` requires to input a non-whitespace char(s) which are consumed for each of the subsequent `%d`.

The effect of *spaces* and `\n` in the following scanf() calls you have isn't quite obvious. But the newline character at the end of each last `scanf()` forces you to input a non-whitespace char. Hence, it looks like `scanf()` requires an extra input.

However, you don't really any whitespace characters here as `%d` would always ignore whitespace characters. So simply remove all *spaces* and `\n` characters from the format strings.

Answer (score 1):

White space characters in the `scanf` format string are directives that mean *read white space characters until you get a non white space character*. A trailing `\n` in your format string causes `scanf` to consume the linefeed that was typed by the user and to keep asking for input until a non white space character is seen, but is left in the input buffer.

To consume the `\n` exactly, you can use this ugly `scanf` format:

```
scanf("%d%*1[\n]", &mprice);
```

Or you can just remove the trailing \n and consume the character with `getchar()` but be aware that neither of these approaches provide for exact matching of the input:

```
scanf("%d", &mprice);
getchar();
```