# Program not running after scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to programming . I am trying to do an assignment but the code doesn't do anything after the first input to scanf . ( I am coding in VS code and i have to run the program again to get the result . until then nothing happens. ) I wrote an another simple code to check if anything is wrong with the code or if it is a IDE problem . Here it is :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int a, b;

    printf("Enter an positive Integer :  ");
    scanf("%i ", &a);
    b = a%2;

    if (b == 0) {
        printf("The given number  is an Even Integer. \a\n ");
    } else { 
        printf("The given Integer is an Odd integer. \n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After the input if I enter a **character** or a **number** and *then press 'Enter'* then it prints out the result. Or else I have to run the program to print the result .

*( I am using code runner ).*

I referred to similar questions on stack overflow and applied some solutions like ' removing the \n in scanf ' and 'leaving a space before the %i in scanf ' but nothing works .

Your help is MUCH appreciated.

Comment: it is not a VS code problem because i tried running the code in an online c compiler and sill it does the same thing mentioned above .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space after `%i`. Specifically, `scanf("%i ", &a)` should be `scanf("%i", &a)`. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `scanf ( "%i " , &a ) ;` with `scanf("%d",&a)` and you are good to go ! for more explaination refer [Refer this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905094/scanf-extra-input-required)